# Using PayPal SDK got this "delegate does not respond to selector adjust amounts" when checking out

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

Using the PayPal SDK - When checking out I receive the following - Delegate does not respond to selector "adjust amounts"

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Also when users, use paypal account that are outside the USA they get "System error. Please try again later (ID 520002)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is misuse of dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled which leads to the error. If you enable it, you need to use shipping address to update the payment amount, tax, currency, and shipping values of the payment. Then you need to pass PaypayAddress to the PayPalPaymentDelegate in the AdjustAmounts method. The error jumps out if you haven't done that. I guess.

A quick solution:
Disable dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled will work. I got same problem as yours and fixed it in this way.

[PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = FALSE;